# VoIP traffic modeling in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, telecommunication

I am trying to model VoIP traffic as an on-off modulated Poisson process in Simulink. There is an example in Matlab help named Markov-modulated Poisson process, but the problem is that in this model the on and off periods of the VoIP traffic have the same exponential distribution. How can I modify this model to have different distributions for the on and off periods?
Thanks